# Hyperledger fabric join a channel with 1.4.4 peer local msp

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

AFAIK, hyperledger fabric 1.4.4 allow "NodeOUs" by creating a `config.yaml` file inside of a msp directory.

I am trying to join the network with local peer msp. But the network always return below error.
`Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500: access denied for [JoinChain][myorg]: [Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [The identity is not an admin under this MSP [MYORG]: The identity does not contain OU [ADMIN], MSP: [MYORG]]])`

Also the structure of my peer's local msp directory have

```sh
msp
  `- admincerts
  `- cacerts
         `- ca-cert.pem
  `- signcerts
         `- signcert.pem
  `- keystore
         `- secret
  `- config.yaml
```

The contents of `msp/config.yaml` is like below.

```
NodeOUs:
  Enable: true
  ClientOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: client
  PeerOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: peer
  AdminOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: admin
  OrdererOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: orderer
```

My guess is NodeOUs is worked because there is no problem booting up the peer without admincerts. So I think I need to configure channel join policies but I cannot find out any policy references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for organization policies in your configtx.yaml which would be quite similar to this:

```
1. For orderer:

    Readers:
    Type: Signature
    Rule: "OR('ordererMSP.member')"
    Writers:
    Type: Signature
    Rule: "OR('ordererMSP.member')"
    Admins:
    Type: Signature
    Rule: "OR('ordererMSP.member')"

2. For MYORG:

    Readers:
    Type: Signature
    Rule: "OR('MYORGMsp.admin', 'MYORGMsp.peer', 'MYORGMsp.client')"
    Writers:
    Type: Signature
    Rule: "OR('MYORGMsp.admin', 'MYORGMsp.client')"
    Admins:
    Type: Signature
    Rule: "OR('MYORGMsp.admin','MYORGMsp.client')"
```

Now because the policies for orderer are generic so the genesis block creation works well. But the problem starts while peers try to join channel as the policies for the peer orgs are specific to user types which are either admin, peer or client.

So to resolve this you have to pass **OU** as either **admin, peer, client or orderer** to your certificates while enrolling them with Fabric-CA. Then only the certificate will be valid for doing particular operations using those certificates. Here is an example for generating admin certificate:

```
fabric-ca-client enroll --caname ca.example.com --csr.names C=SG,ST=Singapore,L=Singapore,O=$ORG_NAME,OU=admin -m admin -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:$PORT
```

Comment: I have one more question. From your example for enrolling admin cert, but AFAIK if I register the identity type as a client, the OU value is not changed. My fabric-ca-client version is 1.4.4 and I cannot change OU value when enroll it.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `configtx.yaml` you used has (at least):

```
Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_4_3: true
        V1_1: true
```

In the client that you are using to join the peer, run (check the certificate path):

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in $CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH/signcerts/signcert.pem
```

Check that `OU` includes `admin`.

You can also check that the certificate is signed by `myorg`'s CA:

```
openssl verify -CAfile path-to-myorg-msp-as-specified-in-configtx-yaml/cacerts/ca-cert.pem $CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH/signcerts/signcert.pem
```

More information here: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/msp.html#identity-classification